# Server socket accepting connection only once

Tags: c, sockets, server, client

I am learning to work with C sockets, and have created very basic client and server programs for the same

Client Program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <sys/types.h>          // contains the type definitions related to sockets
#include <sys/socket.h>         // contains the socket API

#include <netinet/in.h>         // used to store the address information

int main() {
    int network_socket;         // the socket is represented by an integer value, which can be used later to access the socket
    network_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);           // opening a socket, defining the domain of the socket, type of socket, and protocol used

    struct sockaddr_in server_address;          // creating an address structure for the server
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;        // specifying the type of socket as internet
    server_address.sin_port = htons(9002);      // specifying the port number
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; // specifying the address 

    int connection_status = connect(network_socket, (struct sockaddr*) &server_address, sizeof(server_address));        // The function to establish a connection
    if(connection_status == -1) {
        printf("Connetion Failed");
    }

    char server_response[256];
    recv(network_socket, &server_response, sizeof(server_response), 0);

    printf("The server sent the data: %s", server_response);

    return 0;
}
```

Server Program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#include <netinet/in.h>

int main() {
    char server_message[256] = "You have reached the server\n";

    int server_socket;
    server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port = htons(9002);
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    bind(server_socket, (struct sockaddr*) &server_address, sizeof(server_address));
    listen(server_socket, 5);       // 5 indicates the backlog, i.e. how many sockets can be waiting for this connection at a given point of time

    int client_socket;
    client_socket = accept(server_socket, NULL, NULL);

    send(client_socket, server_message, sizeof(server_message), 0);

    return 0;
}
```

The given programs work well for the first time that I compile and run both of them, and I get the desired response upon running the client program

`The server sent the data: You have reached the server`

But when I try running the client program once again, I get the following message

`Connection FailedThe server sent the data:`

Even when I terminate the running server program, re-compile it and run it again, the same thing happens

Comment: Your server needs to accept connections in a *loop*. Right now, it accepts a connection, sends a message, and then exits.

Comment: Also please note that `&server_response` is a pointer to the array itself, and will have the type `char (*)[256]`. Usually you pass a pointer to the first element of the array, which is plain `server_response`.

Comment: You also need to add more error checking. And if there's an error, you should not continue the program as if nothing happened. Also note that TCP is a streaming protocol, with no packets or data boundaries, it's all a stream of bytes. As such, the data in a single `send` call might need multiple `recv` calls to be able to receive all the data.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm receiving the data correctly for the first connection. Then I'm restarting the server and trying to establish a connection again. That's when it fails. Since this is just a dummy program, I haven't written a loop to accept connections, rather am just restarting the server. But it isn't working after the first time

Comment: Don't you need to close the socket after use?

Comment: The problem is the lack of error checking. If you add error checking you will likely see errors from the server. This is because you need to learn more about [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol), especially its [*states*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#/media/File:Tcp_state_diagram_fixed_new.svg). After the server program exits, the socket is closed and will end up in the `TIME_WAIT` state. That will last for a couple of minutes. During that time you can't create a socket bound to the same interface and port again.

Comment: As a workaround enable the `SO_REUSEADDR` for the server socket, before you bind it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude you are likely correct, however the *server* will enter `TIME_WAIT` only if the server closes its end of the connection first.  As neither party is explicitly closing their sockets, whether the server enters `TIME_WAIT` is a timing issue dependent on which process actually terminates first.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your server to support multiple clients sequentially using a loop.For supporting multiple concurrent clients, you have to use threads or NIO (e.g., `epoll()` or `select()`).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <error.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define ERROR  -1
#define BACKLOG 5
#define NOEXIT  0
#define EXIT    1

const char *server_message = "You have reached the server\n";

int open_server_socket(int port) {
    int server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);  
    if (server_socket==ERROR) error(EXIT,errno, "socket");
    
    struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port = port;
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
      
    if (bind(server_socket, (struct sockaddr*) &server_address,
             sizeof(server_address)) ==ERROR) error(EXIT, errno, "bind");

    if (listen(server_socket, BACKLOG) ==  ERROR) error(EXIT, errno, "listen");
    
    return server_socket;
}

void handle_client(int server_socket) {
  int client_socket = accept(server_socket, NULL, NULL);
  if (client_socket == ERROR) goto END;
  
  if (write(client_socket, server_message, sizeof(server_message) == ERROR))
    goto END;
  
  close(client_socket); 
  
 END:
  if(errno) error(NOEXIT, errno, "client");
}

int main() {
  int server_socket = open_server_socket(9005); 
  while(true) handle_client(server_socket);
}
```

In addition, I have mildly addressed the lack of error handling issue that was pointed out by [Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude).

Comment: Lack of error handling is still a major problem. And will lead to the same problem that the OP have when closing down and restarting the server too close to each other.